# Adding Jquery library via module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, module

I need to Add Jquery Library to header using my custom Module.
so that I Create requirejs-config.js file under Vendorname_ModuleName\view\frontend
and Its As Below

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            mypluginjs: 'Vendorname_ModuleName/js/mypluginjs'
        }
    }
};
```

then I added mypluginjs file under **view\frontend\web\js**  named **mypluginjs.js**

Then I added My js script to phtml as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','mypluginjs '],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {

//code here

    });
});
</script>
```

but its showing error.I think not loading  mypluginjs  .what was the issue.
is there any way to add custom jquery plugin via module

Comment: have you regenerate the static content ?

Comment: yes.I tried it also reindex and others

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: is my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add to your phtml file

```
        <script>
          require(
              [
                  'jquery'
              ],
              function($) {
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                    alert("Hello i am here");
                  });
              }
          );
        </script>
```

Comment: I already added but its returning error

Comment: remove your requirejs-config.js file and what error come ? please show your error

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Favico is not defined
    at argus-all-weather-tank.html:40
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5232)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:4884)

Comment: please remove all content from phtml and only add this and check it might be somthing wrong with your phtml file.remove your old js call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

> requirejs-config.js

```
  var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            mypluginjs: 'Arsenaltech_Customer/js/mypluginjs'               
        }
    }
};
```

> Mypluginjs.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui"
], function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.widget('modulename.customname', {
        _create: function() {
            var yourData = this.options;
            /*this.options contaion all variables which you pass in it for use in your javascript code */
            console.log(this.options); 
            // here you can write your javascript code as your requirement
        }
    });
    return $.modulename.customname;
});
```

> Now you can use anywhere in your template file by below method:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "body" : {
             "mypluginjs": 
                    {

                        "yourvar1": "12", 
                        "yourvar2" : "21"
                    }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: no still not loading

Comment: can you show my your mypluginjs.js file ?

Comment: I have update my answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Move your JS code into Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/test.js

**Step 2:** Create requirejs-config.js file in Vendor/Module/view/frontend/ with content:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        testjs:     'Vendor_Module/js/test'
    }
}};
```

**Step 3:** add this at the end of your template file where you want this JS to be called

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Vendor_Module/js/test": {}
    }
}</script>
```