# how to add jquery on magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, jquery

I am using Magento 2, in my case I want to add an element after another using jQuery, can anyway tell me how to it, the best practice please

For example i want to insert a div with class **'one'** after another div with class **'two'**

```
$(".one").insertAfter(".two");
```

> thank you in advance !

Comment: check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/306834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use jQuery in Magento you need to add `require` before using jQuery, like this:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($){
        $( "<div class='one'>Test</div>" ).insertAfter( ".inner" );
    });
</script>
```

Here is the detail of how insertAfter works is here: https://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

**#Edited**

If you want to do it in js level, then you don't need `require` you can use this criteria to add your js.

Add your js file in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/your_js_file.js`

then add `requirejs-config.js` in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

content of `requirejs-config.js` will be:

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'myfile': 'Vendor_Module/js/your_js_file'
},
 shim: {
    'myfile': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
}
};
```

Now you can use any `jQuery` functions in your file without using `require`

Comment: can i do this by creating a folder  js to declare it into the file .js ?

Comment: Yes you can do this

Comment: can you update your answer plz to see how

Comment: see updated answer